# Can I define my binary framework which has open source dependencies without specifying the 'type' parameter in each of my framework's dependencies?

Tags: swift-package-manager, swift-package

I'm having a problem defining the `Package.swift` file for my binary closed-source dynamic framework which depends on a number of non-binary open-source dynamic frameworks.

My `Package.swift` file looks like this:

```swift
// swift-tools-version: 5.8
// The swift-tools-version declares the minimum version of Swift required to build this package.

import PackageDescription
import Foundation

let package = Package(
    name: "MyLibrary",
    platforms: [
        .iOS(.v12)
    ],
    products: [
        .library(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            targets: ["MyLibraryWrapper"]
        ),
    ],
    dependencies: [
        .package(url: "<dependency-url>", branch: "master"),
    ],
    targets: [
        .target(
            name: "MyLibraryWrapper",
            dependencies: [
                .target(name: "MyLibrary"),
                .product(name: "<dependency-product-name>", package: "<dependency-package-name>")
            ],
            path: "MyLibraryWrapper"
        ),
        .binaryTarget(
            name: "MyLibrary",
            url: "<url-to-xcframework-zip>",
            checksum: "<checksum>"
        )
    ]
)
```

The package builds successfully. However, when I add it to any app, I get the following runtime error:

```
Library not loaded: @rpath/<dependency-product-name>.framework
```

The only workaround I know is to add  `type: .dynamic` to the [library(name:type:targets:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/product/library(name:type:targets:)) declaration in the `Package.swift` file of each of my framework's dependencies. This requires me to fork each of my framework's dependencies and maintain the forks. That's not something I'm keen on.

Is there is a better, simpler solution to this problem?

## Notes

1. I need to declare the `MyLibraryWrapper` target in my `Package.swift` file because the [binaryTarget(name:url:checksum:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/target/binarytarget(name:url:checksum:)) method does not offer a `dependencies` parameter.
2. The `MyLibraryWrapper` directory which the `MyLibraryWrapper` target declares as its `path` contains a single empty source file and nothing else.
3. I tried declaring the `type` of `MyLibrary` as [.dynamic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/product/library/librarytype/dynamic) via the [library(name:type:targets:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/product/library(name:type:targets:)) method. I was hoping that Swift Package Manager would do the right thing of dynamically linking `MyLibrary` and its dependencies. Sadly, declaring the `type` of `MyLibrary` as [.dynamic](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/product/library/librarytype/dynamic) results in a `"Multiple commands produce MyLibrary.framework"` build error.
4. The non-binary dynamic frameworks which `MyLibrary` depends on do not specify an explicit `type` value in their `Package.swift` files. This is based on Apple's recommendation in the [library(name:type:targets:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/packagedescription/product/library(name:type:targets:)) method documentation: "It’s recommended that you don’t explicitly declare the type of library, so Swift Package Manager can choose between static or dynamic linking based on the preference of the package’s consumer."